# Reading expect script commands from file

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, expect, tcl

I need to update configurations of several gateways...I have two files:

File 1 (`ip.txt`) : Holds gateways’ IP addresses --->
This files gets updated every month.

File 2 (`cmd.txt`): Holds commands to make config change on gateway --->
This also gets updated from time to time.

So far I have two scripts......

Script 1  i.e., `script1.sh`:
basically script1 is reading Gateway IPs and passign it to expect script to login to the Gateway.

```
#!/bin/sh
for device in `cat /home/ip.txt`;do
./step_3 $device;
done
```

Second Script

```
#!/bin/expect -f

set IP [lindex $argv 0]

spawn ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no user@$IP

expect "password: "

send "difficult123\r"

expect "GBU_0:"

send "su -\r"
expect "Password: "

send "verydifficult123\r"

expect "GBI_0:"

send "/17.1/bin/cli.exe\r"

expect "USERNAME : "

send "GOOR\r"

expect "PASSWORD : "

send "DIFFICULT123\r"

expect "] "
****************** POINT 1 - Only One Change command shown -- I have multiple commands here to insert-----

send "CHG-MEM:SEV=CRITICAL;\r"

expect "(Y/N) :"

send "Y\r"

expect "]"
******************** POINT 2

send "exit\r"

expect "0:~> "

send "exit\r"

expect "logout"

send "exit\r"

expect "closed"

expect eof
```

If I hard code expect commands b/w Point 1 and 2 then everything works like a charm (I have multiple commands)...
How can I call expect command b/w Point 1 and 2 from file ... i.e., I do not want to hard code the commands inside but rather in a separate file so user can update the commands file without touching the script and run it.....
passing IP to expect script works great ... I am not sure if I can pass expect command from file as well.

Answer (score 1):

TCL can easily include and run commands from some other file; the [`source(n)`](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TclCmd/source.htm) command for example allows one to say

```
#!/usr/bin/env expect

package require Tcl 8.5

set IP [lindex $argv 0]
set include_file [lindex $argv 1]

# ... begin commands before here

catch {source $include_file} result options
if {[dict get $options -code] != 0} {
    puts stderr "could not source $include_file: $result"
    exit 1
}

# end commands after here ...
```

with this saved as `runner` one can then have an include file

```
$ cat runthese 
puts a
puts b
puts c
$ expect runner 127.0.0.1 runthese
a
b
c
$
```

though of course the `runthese` or whatever file to include can instead have `send` and `expect` as necessary.

Comment: Thank you ....So.. i should add -->  catch {source.......until exit 1 }  part b/w point 1 and 2 in my second script and save it as a runner ....create another file runthese with send and expect commands..... and run script as  "expect runner 127.0.0.1 runthese" ....Is 127.0.0.1 fixed IP ..In my case if i have 100 diff IPs and i would like to ssh to each and then run the runthese commands...Please elaborate on 127.0.0.1 a bit or is that an actual file that has a list of IPs..... Thank you again so much for your time and it has been a great help.....Thanks

Comment: It worked beautifully.....in my first script i added runthese (like below) and added include file in second script.....and it worked like a charm
*********** for device in `cat /home/ip.txt`;do
./step_3 $device runthese;
done